# Unreal type, camera-mapped sphere mask in Blender

Tags: materials, camera, vector-mapping

There is a "Sphere mask"- node in the Unreal- material editor, which you can use to have a spherical gradient texture tracked to the position of the object but always facing the camera and ignoring the normals of the object. I want to do the same in Blender.

So, basically the effect in the linked image. Here i used a mapping node to manually move and scale the gradient to match the monkey, but if i move the camera or the monkey the gradient of course does not follow.

Any way of having the gradient always be centered on the object?

[image]

Comment: Use camera in the texture coordinates node.

Comment: I did in the example image, but because the gradient is only mapped to the camera, if i move the object the gradient doesn't stay centered on it.That's the problem.